# How to write pandas command more efficiently using for loop

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
No   ID PCCount Status A_PCT 
 1    0    1      A      1
 2    1    2      B      1
 3    2    9      C      1
 4    2    9      A      2
 5    3    10     C      0 
 5    2    9      C      2
 7    3    10     B      0 
 8    4    12     C      1
```

What I am trying to do is to calculate the last column using existing information.

i is in range(1 to 4)
Approved_PCT = the number of rows with (ID == i & status == A)

---

I have a quick solution

```
df['A_PCT'] = df[(df['status'] == 'A') & (df['ID'] == 0)].No.nunique()
df['A_PCT'] = df[(df['status'] == 'A') & (df['ID'] == 1)].No.nunique()
df['A_PCT'] = df[(df['status'] == 'A') & (df['ID'] == 2)].No.nunique()
df['A_PCT'] = df[(df['status'] == 'A') & (df['ID'] == 3)].No.nunique()
```

Is there anyway make it more efficient

```
for i in range(1,4): 
        df['Approved_PCT'] = df[(df['status'] == 'A') & (df['ID'] == i)].No.nunique()
```

i tried this method, but it didn't return the count I want, instead, it summed up all the values, and df['Approved_PCT] only has one unique value. I need df['Approved_PCT] to have four unique values

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform`, then filter with `where`:

```
df['Approval_PCT'] = (df.groupby(['Status','ID']).No.transform('nunique')
                        .where(df['Status'].eq('A'))   # only choose `A`
                     )
```

Or `query` then `groupby().transform`:

```
df['Approval_PCT'] = (df.query('Status=="A"')
                        .groupby('ID')['No'].transform('nunique')
                     )
```

Output:

```
   No  ID  PCCount Status  A_PCT  Approval_PCT
0   1   0        1      A      1           1.0
1   2   1        2      B      1           NaN
2   3   2        9      C      1           NaN
3   4   2        9      A      2           1.0
4   5   3       10      C      0           NaN
5   5   2        9      C      2           NaN
6   7   3       10      B      0           NaN
7   8   4       12      C      1           NaN
```

Comment: In this case, I want the status to count only A. So id == i and status == A. If you groupby, wouldn't that cover status A B and C?